# wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) in Rails 5.1 partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am building a simple wiki app and am trying to pass an object and index/enum to a partial so when a button is clicked a modal pops up and I can edit a user.  Here is my index view code:

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each_with_index do |u, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= u.full_name %></td>
      <td><%= u.email %></td>
      <td><%= u.role %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Modify", '#edit-user-modal', data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#edit-user-modal#{index}" }, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success' %></td>
      <%= render 'edit_user_modal', u: u, index: index %>
     <% end %>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my modal code:

```html
<div id="edit-user-modal<%= index %>" class="modal fade new-user-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Modify User</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for(u, url: '/user_admin', method: 'patch') do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :full_name, class: 'control-label' %>
            <%= f.text_field :full_name, class: "form-control" %>
            <%= f.label :email, class: 'control-label' %>
            <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
            <%= f.label :password, "Enter existing or New Password", class: 'control-label' %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, "Enter existing or New Password Confirmation", class: "form-control" %>
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, class: 'control-label' %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
            <%= f.label :role, class: 'control-label' %>
            <%= f.text_field :role, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Create Users", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've setup something like this before, and had no problems passing locals like this, but in this particular case the error raises on `wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)`

I've used this same tactic for passing locals in a partial before and had no problems.  But for some reason I'm getting this error.

Note I am on Rails 5.1 and Ruby 2.4.0

**Update Stacktrace**

```html
ActionView::Template::Error - wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2):
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template/error.rb:67:in `initialize'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:321:in `handle_render_error'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:160:in `rescue in render'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:342:in `block in render_partial'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:331:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
  app/views/user_admin/index.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_user_admin_index_html_erb__1902393957041503973_70195080307960'
  activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:41:in `each'
  app/views/user_admin/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_user_admin_index_html_erb__1902393957041503973_70195080307960'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:51:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/nynhex/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:33:in `default_render'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
  actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:46:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:832:in `call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.9.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  puma (3.9.0) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.9.0) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
  puma (3.9.0) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
  puma (3.9.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the partial :)

Check out the line below:

```html
  <%= f.password_field :password, "Enter existing or New Password Confirmation", class: "form-control" %>
```

The second argument is meant to be the label and appears to be a simple copy and paste error from the line above. If you remove that text, all will be well.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
  <%= render 'edit_user_modal', locals: {u: u, index: index} %>
```

Should be this

```
  <%= render partial: 'edit_user_modal', locals: {u: u, index: index} %>
```

or

```
  <%= render 'edit_user_modal', u: u, index: index %>
```

Comment: Or it can be `<%= render 'edit_user_modal', u: u, index: index %>`

Comment: @AtulKhanduri: it used to be a haml-only syntax if I'm not mistaken. Haven't touched ERB for years. Are you positive it works there?

Comment: No, it can be used in `html.erb`. I used to use this a lot & prefer this syntax over the one you've provided as there's no need to write `partial` & `locals`.

Comment: @AtulKhanduri: indeed, I use that form in haml. Don't use the "full" one.

Comment: I've tried both: <%= render partial: 'edit_user_modal', locals: {u: u, index: index} %> and <%= render 'edit_user_modal', u: u, index: index %> and I still get the same error.  I've already tried this before which is why I asked.  For some reason it's not liking the arguments for locals that I'm passing it.

Comment: @nulltek: JFYI, you have two of those. In the question, the first one is alright, but the second is not. Have you checked both occurences?

Comment: @nulltek use one partial only..why you write partial twice?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry for the confusion, I meant I tried it both ways, but I'm only rendering the single partial line.  I've tried it with both syntaxes and no luck.

Comment: @puneet18 I'm not writing the partial twice, it's written once but will render for each object.

Comment: @nulltek: it _should_ work. Show the code and the error that it now raises.

Comment: @nulltek you are rendering twice lines 10 and 16 of your posted erb

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The code is <%= render 'edit_user_modal', u: u, index: index %> and it raises the same error posted in the question.

Comment: @engineersmnky That was a typo, I had pulled that out and edited my question, thanks.  Still not working

Comment: @nulltek: "still not working" - because the code is __not__ `<%= render 'edit_user_modal', u: u, index: index %>` (as per the latest update). Post the actual code you have now. And update the stacktrace.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I haven't updated the question but will now, the current code is `<%= render 'edit_user_modal', u: u, index: index %>` and it's still not working

Comment: @SergioTulentsev stacktrace has been updated but it looks the same.

Comment: @nulltek: what is index.html.erb line 12?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `  <% @users.each_with_index do |u, index| %>` the start of the block.

Comment: @nulltek: weird. It doesn't make sense. At this point I need to see the error myself. Can't say more without it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've actually paired with one of my friends who is a 6 years rails dev and he couldn't figure it out either.  I have another rails 5.1 app where I'm doing the exact same thing and it works fine.  Only difference is the partial name/modal content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this was I was accidentally passing a string inside of a password_field like so

```
<%= f.password_field :password, "Enter existing or New Password Confirmation", class: "form-control" %>
```

It was a total typo that all of us overlooked.  Removed that text which was meant for a form label and it all works :(